# Button in ListView item - change item on click

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="3" Grid.RowSpan="2">
    <Button x:Name="changeItem" Click="changeItem_Click" Visibility="Visible" >
        <Image Source="Assets/TestIcon.png" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="45" Height="45" />
    </Button>
</StackPanel>
```

This XAML code is part of a DataTemplate for the items of a ListView. When a user clicks on one of these buttons different actions shall be triggered. Such as delete the item, modify the item and so on.

So I'd need to find out the index of the item that contains the button in order to access it. How can I do that best?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have event sender object in event handler. Just cast it to FrameworkElement and get data context:

```
var element = sender as FrameworkElement;
Debug.Assert(element != null, "element != null");
var context = element.DataContext as MyDataModel;
Debug.Assert(context != null, "context != null");
```

Where MyDataModel is your data model class.